# How to stop php process in iframe?

Tags: php, iframe, rotator

I have a rotator link and I dont want to allow people to open it in iframe.

How to stop php process in iframe?

```
header("X-FRAME-OPTIONS: DENY");
```

does not work in firefox and chrome. my link is (EDITED)

Comment: Please define *"does not work in firefox and chrome"*. What did you expect? What happened instead?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Bug_writing_guidelines

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Access-control-allow-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) header.

It allows you to control which domain can access or frame your scripts.

You can choose between 3 values :

- Only from the same domain
- Only from a domain listed on a list you made
- From anyone (wildcard)

Answer (score 1):

Since *PHP* is never in an *iframe* but executed on the server side there is no way to reliably know if the request originated from an *iframe* on your site of not.

If your intention *(which is not quite clear)* is to make sure people don't put an *iframe* of your site on another site, then you can check for the *referrer* of the request etc. But most of it can be spoofed.

**Update due to comment:**

Then there is unfortunately no good standardized way of getting this type of information reliably. If you yourself had an iframe on your site and for some reason didn't want that to be able to call your script you could probably do this by adding some *GET* parameters via javascript or something. But since you have pretty good control over your own iframes this shouldn't be a problem.

But when it comes to determining of the request from the browser to your server originated in an iframe or not there is no information in the HTTP header to disclose this. The only thing you could possibly be informed about is if that iframe is from a page hosted on another domain.

But if you have an iframe on your own site, don't add any extra parameters to the request and access your script in it and then *normally* from the browser's *main* window the two requests will look the same on the server.

Comment: I Want my rotator link be opened only directly, not in iframe , frame and object......

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure if I understand your question, but here's a list of things:

- If you want to stop your page being loaded in an iframe, there's not easy way of doing that, if the browser is ignoring `X-Frame-Options: DENY`.
- If you have a link the user can click that opens in the iframe, not the parent frame, you can use the `base` html tag, to specify to the browser to open any links you click in the parent frame, with `<base target="_parent" />`
- If you want to redirect automatically, and that causes an issue when loaded in an iframe because you use headers to do it or something, you could probably use the `base` tag and some javascript to automate clicking on the link as an alternative